# Lazy load angular modules on demand and with permission

Tags: angularjs, security, module, lazy-loading, koa

Take a SaaS company that wants to pack all its services into a single, uhm.. Single Page Application using Angular (1). Now there is a public area (landing page, etc.) and an internal area. There are various layers of protection in the backend. There are different user groups with different privileges.

If the complete app is compiled into a single javascript file, hints for all routes can be found in the JS file quite easily. Then, there are services / $resources for interacting with the API, which again contain quite essential information on the functionality of the application.

Now the question: **How could someone put modules on a certain non-binary protection level, and only load this particular module when the user is authorized to see it, all while not reloading the page?**

I can find a way to lazily add modules to an angular application. I can also protect single files server sided and only send them to authorized users. But that seems like an unscalable hassle when there are more and more user groups.

Do you know any generic libraries for that purpose, ideally in sync with koa, which do not create a vast overhead? Do you know of some grunt / gulp / whatever processes, which help with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use latest ui.router which allows you to lazy load routes. 
https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#lazyload

Also you can use web pack and use multiple entry points to create seperate bundles. https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html

By following above steps you can optimise the app but I don't think that this will add any protection to the web assets. You can minify to make life bit difficult to understand what your JS code is doing.